# Python selenium “while true:” script can't execute driver.get(“URL”)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My script has a while True: script running 24/7. It always hits `print ('False')` every `sleep(55)` seconds, and once the `current_time` is between specified times, it calls `driver.get("URL")` and does a few actions on a website.

But sometimes it hits an error where it cannot open `driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')` and prints the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/insta/users/nycforest/lcf.py", line 254, in <module>
    lcf_time(input_begin_time,input_end_time,input_begin_time2,input_end_time2)
  File "/home/matt/insta/users/nycforest/lcf.py", line 241, in lcf_time
    login()
  File "/home/matt/insta/users/nycforest/lcf.py", line 40, in login
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.70)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 5.4.0-1020-aws x86_64)
```

I tried adding `driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)` after `driver.get('URL')` but it hits the error above

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from datetime import datetime, time
from itertools import islice
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

input_begin_time = time(18,40)
input_end_time = time(18,50)
input_begin_time2 = time(21,20)
input_end_time2 = time(21,30)

opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument('--headless')
opts.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
opts.add_argument('--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess')



def login():
    sleep(2)
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
    sleep(3)

    input_username = driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(username)
    input_password = driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)

    button_login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button')
    button_login.click()

# def other_functions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)

def lcf_time(time_begin1, time_end1, time_begin2, time_end2, curren_time=None):
    current_time = datetime.now().time()
    if time_begin1 < current_time < time_end1 or time_begin2 < current_time < time_end2:
        login()
        # other_functions()
        driver.close()
    else:
        print("False")


while True:
    lcf_time(input_begin_time,input_end_time,input_begin_time2,input_end_time2)
    sleep(55)
```

The odd thing is: I have a few different scripts running ***the exact same script with different variables*** and it some scripts are fine and others consistently hit this 60% of the time. I need a more reliable way to `driver.get("URL")` 24/7

Is this a compatibility issue? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you try to put driver.set_page_load_timeout(20) before driver.get(url)

Comment: use driver.quit() instead of close.  You should probably also update chrome and chromedriver.

Comment: Instagram is production site where you can't keep anything running 24/7 all the time. Such production sites have bot blockers that will either block your execution using captcha or some other third party tools.

Comment: @Dev 90% of the time the browser is closed